# How many ways can $10$ different kids be distributed to $4$ distinct classes?

Tags: combinatorics

I want to find the number ways to distribute 10 different kids to 4 different classes, such that each class has at least 2 kids.

My attempt: First distribute 8 kids to 4 classes such that each class has exactly 2 kids. Then there are 16 option to split the remaining 2 kids.

This is my result: $\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}*16$ which is wrong. I don't have exact answer but I know it's either: $226800, 75600, 44100$.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the answer is one of those 3 options?

Comment: Yes. Do you think my prof phrased the question wrong? Because he didn't include the words "different" and "distinct", I thought it's obvious.

Comment: I think your method counts arrangements multiple times. Suppose students A and B are put into room 1 during the initial distribution of 2 kids per room, and then student C ends up in room 1 when deciding on the last 2 kids. This scenario would be counted again if B and C went to room 1 at first, followed by A.

Comment: When nothing is mentioned about its distinctness, then we take it as distinct by convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there are 2 different size types for classes, $3,3,2,2$ or $4,2,2,2$. For the first one, choose firstly which classes will have $3$ kids, $\binom{4}{2}$, then distribute the kids, $\binom{10}{3} \cdot \binom{7}{3} \cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot \binom{2}{2}$. Do the same for the other size type and you will arrive at $ \binom{4}{2} \cdot \binom{10}{3} \cdot \binom{7}{3} \cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot \binom{2}{2} + \binom{4}{1} \cdot \binom{10}{4} \cdot \binom{6}{2} \cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot \binom{2}{2} = 226800$

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is 226800.

The sizes of the classes can be $(2,2,2,4)$ (+ any permutation) or $(2,2,3,3)$ (+ any permutation).

$$\binom{10}{4}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{1} + \binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{2} = 226800$$